# How can I embed Youku or Tudou videos in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, video, embed, fullscreen

Or open them in a UIWebView? Their videos are in .swf format though.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Okay, so I can get it to play in UIWebView, also when you click on the video in the UIWebView it will play the video in fullscreen. So am wondering if I can just get the code of when it clicks to fullscreen, and use it in some button I have.

Did that make sense?

Oh and thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will easily be able to verify on the internet, Flash (.swf) is not supported on iOS devices. Maybe they offer their videos in another format, otherwise this won't work.

**Update:** I guess you're just opening the website in your web view. So that means on their web site they have an iOS compatible stream. You can fetch the stream data from the website's source code and build your own web site (stored locally on the device) that only displays that video stream in an UIWebView. Or you use MPMoviePlayer or HTTPLiveStream, whatever. However, make sure that this is allowed/legal, I can't help you there since I guess it heavily depends on what you want to do with your app.

Comment: thanks, I think I'll have to find out what other video formats they offer. Youku has their own iPhone app, is there a way for me to find out what video format they used?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, maybe you could monitor your network activity or take a look into the device logs. Or maybe Youko even publishes this information somewhere on AppStore etc. If you want further information about this and can't find it anywhere, you might want to consider opening a new question regarding this (e.g. "How to find out what video format is streamed to the device in an app").

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your edited question, but please bear in mind that you've got to make sure what you're doing is legal (i.e. I'm not so sure if they're happy when you distribute a Toudou app in app store).

Comment: not a Tudou app, just Tudou or Youku videos :)) thanks for the suggestion, I will give that a shot :)

Answer (score 7):

Try embed the iframe snippet from Youku into your webview

```
<iframe height="498" width="510" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
 src="http://player.youku.com/embed/XNTY4ODU0NzQ0"></iframe>
```

I got it working on Android, but not tried it on iOS yet.

Answer (score 6):

```html
<video width="480" height="320"
 src="http://v.youku.com/player/getRealM3U8/vid/XMzkxMTM3MDQw/type//video.m3u8"
 controls>
    <embed src="http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMzkxMTM3MDQw/v.swf"
     allowFullScreen="true" quality="high" width="480" height="320"
     align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always"
     type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
</video>
```

Just use the above HTML in a UIWebView for Youku. It can be played on iOS device and PC. Replace the `XMzkxMTM3MDQw` with the corresponding code of the video.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://blog.xiaohai.co/archives/youku-html5/) to get the url of .m3u8 file for a youku video by its ID, and simply embed it into a `<video>` tag